# Finite Group (Non-)Isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am poking at reproducing some fundamental research in group theory.  In particular, I want to reproduce the [OEIS sequence #1](https://oeis.org/A000001).  The crux of the problem is not generating potential groups, this can be accomplished by a sat-solver and about 20 lines of code, but determining which of those groups so generated are isomorphic.

The finite group isomorphism algorithms are tractable, but computationally a bit hairy, so I am keen to determine what heuristics can be employed to save some compute on clearly not isomorphic groups.  A few obvious examples are:

- Groups with different order
- Groups with different Caylee skeleton (number of non-self identity elements)

In short, I would love some form or precomputation or fingerprint that I can compute to avoid comparing obviously different groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will want to look at the publications by James Wilson at Colorado State University who has been doing this kind of thing for quite large groups.

Comment: Though interesting, if I understand correctly the algorithms only apply to a limited class of finite groups

Answer (score 0):

You could apply the KBMAG procedure [[GAP algebra package]](https://gap-packages.github.io/kbmag/).

It attempts to obtain an [automatic structure](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.73.6551&rep=rep1&type=pdf)  for the group: essentially a collection of finite state automata that define the group, which can then be compared for equality. All finite groups have such a structure.

An alternative implementation is [MAF](https://sourceforge.net/projects/maffsa/).